# how to mount host directory to container VOLUME?

Tags: docker

The mysql Dockerfile have define a `VOLUME`:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

I want to mount my host mysql data to the container directory `/var/lib/mysql`.

```
$ docker run -d -v /my-host-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

But when I exec to the container, I check the /var/lib/mysql directory, it not same with my host directory.

Comment: Are you running Docker on Linux, or are you using `boot2docker` under Windows or OS X?

Comment: Using `Volume` in your Dockerfile is for exposing volumes to another host when using `--volumes-from` not to mount volumes into the container.

Comment: am trying to do the same..  using -v works but i would like to configure via dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/3599):

> ### Volume that overrides a Dockerfile VOLUME doesn't mount into container

A [`Dockerfile` `VOLUME` directive](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume) will make a container create (when run) a volume in `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir`

That would make a mount directive (the `-v /my-host-data:/var/lib/mysql` of the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run)) ignored, because `/var/lib/mysql` is already assigned to a filesystem.